# How to delete loaded Jar files in tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want UN-deploy and delete the running application in tomcat without restarting the tomcat server from other application in the same tomcat.
But the loaded jar files are not deleting in my webapps/lib folder.
May be they are using in Tomcat JVM.

For UN-deploying i use code and then i am trying delete
"http://Server-IP:port/manager/html/undeploy?path=/applicationName"

tried stop also
"http://Server-IP:port/manager/html/stop?path=/applicationName"

Please help me :)

Thank U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to set antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" in Tomcat/conf/context.xml.

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: No problem. Nice to hear that.